# Expandable divs with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue whereby due to the structure of my html, when one div is expanded the whole row moves down. I am having a bit of a hard time finding a fix for this. I have looked on here but could not find a resolution. Any ideas would be great. This is my structure (with div 1 expanded to show the nature of the issue):

```
expandable div 1  |  expandable div 2
                  |
                  |  expandable div 4
                  |
expandable div 3  |
```

---

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
          expandable div 1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="panel">
          expandable div 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="panel">
          expandable div 3
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="panel">
          expandable div 4
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you want it to expand? Do you want the expanded div to overlap the divs below?

Comment: Ideally i would like the content to move down accordingly. If its in one column, it wont affect the other? if that makes sense ;)

Comment: @justanotherrrr can you maybe add how do you want it to look like ?

Comment: Do you know about bootstrap collapse? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/

Comment: Hi yes i do, but unable to use them because i can only use one html template to drive my content and the bootstrap collapse relies on id's?

Comment: what version of bootstrap you are using?

Comment: hi @justanotherrrr, try to use the collapse function. You could do this either by using the bootstrap collapse code, or create this in jQuery. Do you know about jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you don't want to use the bootstrap collapse I suggest to do this with jQuery (see below for an example).

**Your `HTML`:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header"><span>Expand</span>

    </div>
    <div class="content" style="display: none;"padding : 10px;>
        Suprise!
    </div>
</div>
```

**Now the `jQuery`:**

```
$(".header").click(function () {

    $header = $(this);

    $content = $header.next();

    $content.slideToggle(300, function () {

        $header.text(function () {              
            return $content.is(":visible") ? "Collapse" : "Expand";
        });
    });

});
```

Something like this will work.

Consider `CSS` for the style display.